# Greater than IE8 or not IE conditional in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, conditional-statements

Normally for conditional script loading I would write something such as this

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
    <script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/scripts.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/scripts-ie8.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

However, I'd like to use Wordpress' enqueue function to make use of its dependency relations. I know that you can write conditions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214782/enqueueing-ie-conditional-stylesheets-in-wordpress-the-right-way):

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'so27214782_ie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ie.css', array(), '27214782', 'all' );

$wp_styles->add_data( 'so27214782_ie', 'conditional', 'IE 6' );
```

However, I am not sure how to apply this to my case. How do you target `gt IE8 | !IE` in that last statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would put this in your functions file

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'scriptsa', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scriptsa.js', array(), '1.0.0', false );
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function( $tag, $handle ) {
    if ( $handle === 'scriptsa' ) {
        $tag = "<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->$tag<!--<![endif]-->";
    }
    return $tag;
}, 10, 2 );

wp_enqueue_script( 'scriptsb', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scriptsb.js', array(), '1.0.0', false );
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', function( $tag, $handle ) {
    if ( $handle === 'scriptsb' ) {
        $tag = "<!--[if lte IE 8]>$tag<![endif]-->";
    }
    return $tag;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Not exactly what I want. I want to load scriptsa.js only when the browser is greater than IE8 OR not IE. I want to load scriptsb.js only when the browser is IE8 or lower.

Comment: I see what you mean, have changed the answer accordingly

Comment: The first part of this didn't work for me. (Guessing because IE10 and more ignore conditional tags all together.) The solution is to change `$tag` to: `$tag = "<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->$tag<!--<![endif]-->";`.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, have edited the answer to include your code